# dropdownlist data is not posted to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a dropdownlist which is populated with data from ViewBag. The code looks like

```
connectionString str=new connectionString();
ViewBag.Dept=str.Department;
```

Now here Department is a table.
I have a dropdownlist

```
@Html.DropDownList("Department", new SelectList(ViewBag.Dept, "Id", "Id"), "Select Department")
```

The Action Method is

```
public ActionResult Edit(Emp emp)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    db.Emps.AddObject(emp);
    return RedirectToAction("Details");
  }
  return View();
}
```

within browser the dropdownlist is showing data from database and when I try to post the form to the server the value is null in case of dropdownlist . The above code is fine with MVC4 but problem with MVC3. Please help me

Comment: by formatting your text make your question more readable..

Comment: What is `ViewBag.Dept` vs `ViewBag.Name`? Is `Department` a property of `Emp`?

Comment: Department is a table and connectionString is the ADO.Net connection string and Department containing properties :Id, Name